# Failing boot, accessing windows repair or factory reset on Windows 8.1 dell laptop

Tags: windows-8, boot, laptop

So my 8.1 dell laptop decided he doesn't want to boot anymore.

When it's trying to boot normally, I see windows sad-face-blue-screen for 100ms and then it restarts and loads automatic repair.
The automatic repair doesn't actually load and I'm stuck with a black screen with the cursor working, but nothing more.

Trying to go into advanced boot using F8, Shift+f8, Fn+F8, before and after the dell logo appears - all failed. It's just keep trying to boot or trying to go into automatic repair window without success.

I ran dell diagnostics tests and everything passed successfully with no errors or issues - so the hardware is good.
Also checked the bios and changed the Function key configuration from Multimedia to Function (and backwards) but it didn't help.

Searched google for 3 hours or so trying to understand whats going on.
I'm pretty experienced with PCs and IT but never faced anything like that...

Will be glad to get some advices! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can download a Windows 8.1 ISO (if you don't have installation media) and put it to USB for example.

[Create Windows 8.1 installation media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media)

You can try fixing boot using "start-up repair" from USB or try a quick fix

from recovery console:

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

where c:\windows should exist else change drive letter accordingly.